# Correct database's structure for table's relations (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `payouts` with column `reciever_id` which by idea must links to primary keys of another ***Two*** tables: `workers` or `doctors`, which is determined by `payouts`.`reciever_type`.
As I understood this structure is a bit wrong.

Would be better to make `payouts` like this ?

```
....
`reciever_worker` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
`reciever_doctor` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
....
```

Or merge tables `workers` and `doctors` to one table.

Table's structure:

```
TABLE `payouts`
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `reciever_type` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `reciever_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `sum` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

TABLE `workers`
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

TABLE `doctors`
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `doctor_fields_1` TEXT ...,
    `doctor_fields_2` ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

How to realize it correctly and standardly?

Comment: *As I understood this structure is a bit wrong*, why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Probably best to post this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is valid only if 'receiver_id` is always either a doctor or a worker.

If you rename those doctor fields in the `doctors` table to something more generic, then it would make perfect sense to have just 1 table for both workers and doctors, with an additional `type` column that would flag them as one or another.

Then, from the `payouts` table you'd use a single column with a FK pointing to this one table with workers and doctors. Also, `receiver_type` would be redundant in `payouts` table.

Having two separate columns in `payouts` table would induce permanent checking if one is empty (`NULL`) or not, or check the type and use either one or another table, and so on. In short, it'd pretty much complicate your life without any benefit.